# How can I show a set B with 8 elements and two operations, such that the axioms of huntington for boolean algebra holds?

Tags: boolean-algebra

If It was about two members I  would have choose B={0,1} with the operations: AND , OR

And prove this.
But how can I do this with 8 elements?

Comment: Hint: you suggest a set with two elements and 8=2^3

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: $B=\{0,1\}$ is the set of one-digit binary numbers. How many three-digit binary numbers are there?